# How to minimize app on pressing back button or home button in android

Tags: java, android, minimize, onbackpressed

I want to show app in particular  size on pressing back button or home button.

Comment: From your extremely limited description, maybe you're looking for Picture-in-Picture: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

The code below demonstrates how to emulate the home button press when the user presses the back button, and in my opinion, treating the back event as a home event is necessary.

```
 public void minimizeApp() 
 {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
 }
```